# ¿Cómo hacer consulta SQL de 2 tablas relacionadas?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy empezando a ver BD, estoy intentando comprender como funcionan las relaciones, el ejemplo que trato de hacer, consiste en tener una tabla profesore y una tabla alumno;

Quiero hacer una consulta a la tabla alumnos, pero con datos del profesor, es decir, decirle que me selecciones a todos los alumnos que tengan como profesor a "profesorX".

Mis tablas y relación, están así:

[image: Tablas]

Aquí estoy haciendo select, pero con el id que ya contiene la tabla alumno, lo que quiero saber, es como indicar que, en lugar de poner el id, ponga el nombre del profesor algo como `***select * from alumno where id_profesor = (select id from profesor where nombre = Gabriel)***` (sé que así no sé escribe, pero no sé como se haga).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Aquí están los registros de mis 2 tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo podrías hacer de esta forma para dejar de anidar las consultas:

```
SELECT alumno.nombre, alumno.profesor
FROM   alumno, profesor
WHERE  alumno.id_profesor = profesor.id_profesor AND
       profesor.nombre = "Gabriel"
```

La forma que pusiste también es una buena idea, y funcionaria sin ningun problema, solo que su clave se llama **id_profesor** y el nombre tendría que ir con comillas dobles " "...

Quedaría así:

```
select * 
from   alumno
where  id_profesor = ( select id_profesor from profesor where nombre = "Gabriel" )
```

Comment: Okey, me funciona. Sí, me acabo de dar cuenta de la clave id_profesor , ya había intentado hacerla, pero me daba error, ya que no ponía entre comillas a Gabriel. 
Pero que diferencia hay (en linea 3) entre: 

alumno.id_profesor = profesor.id_profesor 
 y
 profesor.id_profesor =alumno.id_profesor

Answer (score 2):

Usa un **INNER JOIN** para unir ambas tablas por medio de su llave primaria y llave foránea:

```
SELECT profesor.nombre, profesor.apellido, alumno.nombre, alumno.apellido
FROM profesor 
INNER JOIN profesor.id = alumno.id_profesor
WHERE profesor.nombre = "Gabriel";
```

> Deberías usar INNER JOIN pues buscará todos los registros que estén relacionados en ambas tablas por medio de la comparación de la llave foránea y la llave primaria y al final filtras con un WHERE.

De este modo obtendrás una tabla con el nombre del profesor y todos sus alumnos asociados.

- [JOIN Sintax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)